# Mount snap "core" (3604) ([start snap-core-3604.mount] failed

Tags: ubuntu, hugo, snapcraft

I tried to install `Hugo` with `Snap` on `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` (`GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab125.5 x86_64`). Service `snapd` is running, but I get following error:

> cannot perform the following tasks:
>   - Mount snap "core" (3604) ([start snap-core-3604.mount] failed with exit status                                  1: Job for
>   snap-core-3604.mount failed. See "systemctl status snap-core-3604.mo
>   unt" and "journalctl -xe" for details. )

`systemctl status snap-core-3604.mount` command gives following output:

> ● snap-core-3604.mount - Mount unit for core    Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/systemd/system/snap-core-3604.mount; enabled; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-12-26
>   02:04:46 EST; 25s ago
>       Where: /snap/core/3604
>        What: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_3604.snap   Process: 15732 ExecMount=/bin/mount /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_3604.snap
>   /snap/core/3604 -t squashfs -o nodev,ro
>
> Dec 26 02:04:46 server systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core... Dec
>   26 02:04:46 server mount[15732]: mount: /snap/core/3604: mount failed:
>   Unknown error -1 Dec 26 02:04:46 server systemd[1]:
>   snap-core-3604.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32 Dec
>   26 02:04:46 server systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mount unit for core.
>   Dec 26 02:04:46 server systemd[1]: snap-core-3604.mount: Unit entered
>   failed state.

I got same error, when I issued install command under root privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system you're running isn't *pure* Ubuntu 16.04.3. It is using a non-Ubuntu kernel `2.6.32-042stab125.5 x86_64` which is missing some of the critical features required by `snapd` and snaps themselves. I'd recommend either switching to a stock Ubuntu kernel (if possible), or request your provider updates their kernel.

Comment: I asked my VPS provider, but they said, SolusVM supports only current kernel version.

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to run snaps on that system then I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian 9, Stretch), **with a reboot** after installing snapd.

After the reboot, the above error did not occur when doing e.g.

```
sudo snap install core; 
sudo snap refresh core
sudo snap install --classic certbot # for Let's Encrypt
```